# Help making the HTML/CSS layout work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout

Need some help with making the following layout work in IE:
[image]

Light gray is a browser window. Dark gray is the main content area, centered against the window. To its left is a fixed width yellow box, and to its right is a *variable* width green box. The yellow+blue+green triplet is then repeated down to the bottom (it's basically a simple blog layout).

I got this working in Firefox/Chrome by using negative margin-left and floating all three colored boxes. The IE does not understand it. Tried padding dark gray area on both sides by the width of the yellow box (and then do the overflow: visible, white-space: nowrap in the green box) - still no go.

Any ideas or pointers? What the hell *does* the IE understand?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see some code, please?

Comment: IE is the worst browser on the planet but, as @Dutchie432 said, without the complete markup or a link, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: Well, the mark-up I have is not working, that's why I didn't post it. Let me clean it up and I will add it to the OP.

Comment: By the way... I am really tempted to center the whole thing with a bit of the Javascript. I'm sure it ain't kosher, but it surely the *fastest* solution out there.

Comment: Don't use javascript. It's certainly not appropriate to fallback on JS for purely styling issues...

Answer (score 1):

Alex, the trick here is pretty simple. Position those two *fixed_size* and *var_size* containers absolutely within `#main`. Give `#main` relative positioning. Then given the two absolutely positioned containers negative left and right margins, respectively.

Should certainly work in IE

Good luck and let me know if you need additional help

EDIT: this is the code that is also visible in the Fiddle:

```
<div id="main">
    lorem ipsum
    <div id="left">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="right">&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
    #main { 
margin: 0 auto; position: relative; height: 300px; width: 400px; background: gray; 
}
    #left { 
position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 75px; left: -100px; background: red; 
}
    #right { 
position: absolute; width: 100px; height: auto; right: -100px; background: blue; 
}
```

Obviously, use the appropriate ways to center a div in IE with:

```
    body { 
text-align: center; 
}
    #main { 
text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

EDIT2: Check out the updated jsFiddle.. Hopefully that is something like what you wanted: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2avM7/3/

Comment: This is great. Thank you, Amit. It indeed works as advertised :)

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it does not do exactly what I wanted, but it's close enough to be *the* hint. This is more like it - http://www.jsfiddle.net/2avM7/2/ and yet still it's not quite, because it works only if blue and red are shorter than yellow (using jsfiddle example)... In any case, I redid everything using a table (yes, I know), set is position to relative and added a piece of JS that adjusts table's 'left' on page load. Took me an hour. I will explore beautiful, JS-free options once I have nothing else to do :)

Comment: @Alex: I didn't realize the gray area was supposed to be the `#main` div. I still think what you want to accomplish is possible with pure CSS methods, but if you got it working with JS, that's good enough for now I guess.. gl :)

Comment: @Alex: I've corrected the jsFiddle one last time, I *think* this is what you wanted to do? I really don't know anymore. Here it is: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2avM7/3/ ..Hope you find it helpful in some way or other...

Comment: @Amit - thanks, again it's close, but not quite. The "one" div is supposed to host a blog post content (and red/blue divs - misc. post info), so it needs to be repeatable and in your case repeating it caused red divs to overlap. If you are on FF, have a look at http://bvckup.tumblr.com to see the layout I'm taking about.

Comment: @Alex: I see. First of all, that's a nice layout :) Second, I looked with FF and IE. It looks good in FF and IE8, but the layout gets disordered a bit in IE7. IF you want two quick fixes for IE7 that will make it a little better, I suggest the following IE7 specific rules: `.info { margin-right: -100%; float:none; }` and `.when { float: none; }` that will actually position those two boxes where you want them to be. Other than that, I think I'm gonna leave this question as is as it seems like you've already settled on a different solution...

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a master container, that is wide enough to visit all 3 containers from left to right, so like this:

```
<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto;">
 <div id="fixed_size>Content goes here</div>
 <div id="main_content" style="margin: 0 auto;">Center content</div>
 <div id="variable_size_container">Content for that goes here!<div>
</div>
```

`margin: 0 auto;` does the trick here, it centers a div in the center of its parent div.

Comment: @oezi - but then how do I make *fixed_size* and *variable_size_container* stick to the sides of *main_content*?

Comment: this is an answer from Sander, i've just corrected the code-formatting ;)